# How to dynamically build a PHP array with keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, key

Using PHPGraphlib for a project.

The following adds data to the graph. The array values will be the y-axis value.

```
$graph->addData(array(100,12,43,342,9));
```

If the array has keys, the keys will be the corresponding x-axis values.

```
$data = array("1" => 100, "2" => 12, "3" => 43, "4" => 342, "5" => 9);
```

I need to dynamically build the $data array, starting with a key value of "1", and assign values from a variable separated by commas. The amount of values can change. For example:

```
$values="100,12,43,342,9,22,33";
```

I could explode the data into an array

```
$splits = explode(",",$values);
```

Now I have the number of values. So how do I code a loop to assign these values to incremental keys so that the $data array is essentially:

```
$data = array("1" => 100, "2" => 12, "3" => 43, "4" => 342, "5" => 9, "6" => 22, "7"=> 33);
```

Comment: have you looked at for each loop in the php docs and make a new array as you loop through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this ?

```
<?php
$values="100,12,43,342,9,22,33";
$splits = explode(",",$values);
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($splits); $x++) {
    $data[$x+1] = intval($splits[$x],10);    
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: That's why I did but it wasn't working. So I added the var_dump and realized the data was being assigned as a string, not an integer (that PHPGraphlib required). So I made one change to your code and it now works. Thank you! Changed $data[$x+1] = (int)$splits[$x];

Comment: Good as gold, realized that might be the case so check edit you can also use floatval, snap! nice

Answer (score 2):

This should start the array as one indexed.

```
<?php
$values = "100,12,43,342,9,22,33";
$splits = explode(",", $values);
$data = array_combine(range(1, count($splits)), array_values($splits));
$data = array_map('intval', $data); // converts values to int

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: No problem, could you mark one of the answers as the solution please?

Comment: I liked your answer because it used standard php function, however as each function must in someway loop I tested your code vs mine and performance is far slower using your method